# how to send data in post method to anothe server in node js

Tags: node.js

here is my node.js code

here i am sending some data from node to python

```
let request = http.get("http://localhost:8000/make_json/?api="+{"msg":"hello"}, function (res) {
    let data = '';
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        console.log(res);
    });
});
```

here i am sending data in get method as a query string parameter.
how can i send data in post method in it.

please have a look into it..

Comment: did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTP Client Libraries such as Axios, "https://github.com/axios/axios", which allows you to make GET and POST requests with a post body.
Like this:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user/12345',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to make a post request to an API in nodejs, with your selected data, and then later do a get request to that API in python. You need mongodb for the API.

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var port = 8000;

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://username:password@ds033875.mlab.com:33875/myapidb");

var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userName: String,
  avatar: String
});

var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);

//handling a post request from the front end and saving the data to the mongodb database
app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
  var myData = new User(req.body);
  myData.save()
    .then(item => {
      res.send("item saved to database");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    });
});

//adding it to the API
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
  User.find({}, function (err, users) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem finding the users.");
    res.status(200).send(users.slice(0));
  });
});

//The API url is now going to be localhost:8000/users

// start the server
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started! At http://localhost:' + port);
```

Now in python you would use a GET request for the data in the API you created. After this you would be able to use this data in any server you want in whatever language you want.